# Why am i getting S3 Access error AmazonS3Exception in this AWS Glue Job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am running an AWS Glue Job, and the job is doing what it should, it takes the records from Kinesis stream and is putting it into the data lake. But it ends with a failure and error is as given below:

```
 StreamingQueryException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;
```

Logs from cloudwatch:

```
23/11/06 16:05:59 ERROR GlueExceptionAnalysisListener: [Glue Exception Analysis] {
    "Event": "GlueETLJobExceptionEvent",
    "Timestamp": 1699286759755,
    "Failure Reason": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/azure-activity-to-ocsf-pyspark2.py\", line 300, in <module>\n    \"checkpointLocation\": args[\"TempDir\"] + \"/\" + args[\"JOB_NAME\"] + \"/checkpoint/\",\n  File \"/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py\", line 678, in forEachBatch\n    raise e\n  File \"/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py\", line 668, in forEachBatch\n    query.start().awaitTermination()\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py\", line 101, in awaitTermination\n    return self._jsq.awaitTermination()\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py\", line 1305, in __call__\n    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py\", line 117, in deco\n    raise converted from None\npyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: KKMW0JW7VXKSRCCJ; S3 Extended Request ID: K+qiigS/kCTXbG9A7Tc/I7QtLBpsVSfUxzCApZZAtOwkLjYZgoZPFIiHi7+DlHvYwed9syWsx78=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: K+qiigS/kCTXbG9A7Tc/I7QtLBpsVSfUxzCApZZAtOwkLjYZgoZPFIiHi7+DlHvYwed9syWsx78=\n=== Streaming Query ===\nIdentifier: [id = b3618842-c4c3-4b21-be2e-679f15677208, runId = 68cf2099-0c14-4fbd-a976-51c9e91d6506]\nCurrent Committed Offsets: {KinesisSource[securityLakeAzureActivityStream]: {\"shardId-000000000002\":{\"iteratorType\":\"TRIM_HORIZON\",\"iteratorPosition\":\"\"},\"metadata\":{\"streamName\":\"securityLakeAzureActivityStream\",\"batchId\":\"2\"},\"shardId-000000000001\":{\"iteratorType\":\"TRIM_HORIZON\",\"iteratorPosition\":\"\"},\"shardId-000000000000\":{\"iteratorType\":\"AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER\",\"iteratorPosition\":\"49645809341923458802793491468334882006293674050208137218\"}}}\nCurrent Available Offsets: {KinesisSource[securityLakeAzureActivityStream]: {\"shardId-000000000002\":{\"iteratorType\":\"TRIM_HORIZON\",\"iteratorPosition\":\"\"},\"metadata\":{\"streamName\":\"securityLakeAzureActivityStream\",\"batchId\":\"3\"},\"shardId-000000000001\":{\"iteratorType\":\"TRIM_HORIZON\",\"iteratorPosition\":\"\"},\"shardId-000000000000\":{\"iteratorType\":\"AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER\",\"iteratorPosition\":\"49645809341923458802793546272532794821692601702159482882\"}}}\n\nCurrent State: ACTIVE\nThread State: RUNNABLE\n\nLogical Plan:\nProject [cast(data#18 as string) AS $json$data_infer_schema$_temporary$#27]\n+- Project [UDF(data#5) AS data#18, streamName#6, partitionKey#7, sequenceNumber#8, approximateArrivalTimestamp#9]\n   +- StreamingExecutionRelation KinesisSource[securityLakeAzureActivityStream], [data#5, streamName#6, partitionKey#7, sequenceNumber#8, approximateArrivalTimestamp#9]\n",
    "Stack Trace": [
        {
            "Declaring Class": "deco",
            "Method Name": "raise converted from None",
            "File Name": "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
            "Line Number": 117
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "__call__",
            "Method Name": "answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)",
            "File Name": "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
            "Line Number": 1305
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "awaitTermination",
            "Method Name": "return self._jsq.awaitTermination()",
            "File Name": "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py",
            "Line Number": 101
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "forEachBatch",
            "Method Name": "query.start().awaitTermination()",
            "File Name": "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py",
            "Line Number": 668
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "forEachBatch",
            "Method Name": "raise e",
            "File Name": "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py",
            "Line Number": 678
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "<module>",
            "Method Name": "\"checkpointLocation\": args[\"TempDir\"] + \"/\" + args[\"JOB_NAME\"] + \"/checkpoint/\",",
            "File Name": "/tmp/azure-activity-to-ocsf-pyspark2.py",
            "Line Number": 300
        }
    ],
    "Last Executed Line number": 300,
    "script": "azure-activity-to-ocsf-pyspark2.py"
}
```

The line 300 is this:

```
glueContext.forEachBatch(
    frame=dataframe_KinesisStream_node1,
    batch_function=processBatch,
    options={
        "windowSize": "100 seconds",
        **"checkpointLocation": args["TempDir"] + "/" + args["JOB_NAME"] + "/checkpoint/",**
    },
```

The checkpoint folder is created in S3, I can see that. Temporary folder given in the job settings, is being accessed just fine, i can see the files created by the job there.

This here is the code in the Glue Job: [Github Link](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-security-lake-custom-data/blob/main/azure-activity-to-ocsf-pyspark.py)

Access Role policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-security-data-lake-*/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::securitylake-glue-assets-*/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why this error might be happening? Which bucket is the error for?

Another observation: If i add DeleteObject permission to the above the Glue Job runs forever.

No problem with ACL, SCP etc.

Bucket (Glue script, temporary bucket) Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1683139153218",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::securitylake-glue-assets-123456789-us-east-1/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
                },
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/securityLakeGlueStreamingRole"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Security Lake Bucket policy (Where Glue Job writes to. I can see new files here)

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-security-data-lake-us-east-1-ogt1oa9bot0jmeduqbjxzmxzvu9eij/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-security-data-lake-us-east-1-ogt1oa9bot0jmeduqbjxzmxzvu9eij"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PutSecurityLakeObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "securitylake.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-security-data-lake-us-east-1-ogt1oa9bot0jmeduqbjxzmxzvu9eij/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-security-data-lake-us-east-1-ogt1oa9bot0jmeduqbjxzmxzvu9eij"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceAccount": "644107485976",
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                },
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:securitylake:us-east-1:644107485976:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your second resource name has double dashes at the end, instead of just one. Could that be the issue? Should it be `arn:aws:s3:::securitylake-glue-assets-` instead of `arn:aws:s3:::securitylake-glue-assets--` ?

Comment: @rlhagerm i changed that but that did not help

Answer (score 0):

In your Access Role policy, you need to list the S3 buckets without the wildcard as well as with it, just like you've done with your Security Lake policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::aws-security-data-lake-*/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::aws-security-data-lake-*/",
            "arn:aws:s3:::securitylake-glue-assets-*/",
            "arn:aws:s3:::securitylake-glue-assets-*/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
}
```

Ideally, I wouldn't use wildcards in the S3 bucket name at all, but it should work now.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help. I also tried with actual full names and no wildcards. We have used wildcards because the buckets were getting created from a cloudformation

Comment: Based on the 403 error, it's certain that the Spark cluster is not authorized to write to the S3 destination. To resolve this error, you should:

Check S3 Permissions: Ensure that the IAM role or user which executes the AWS Glue job has the necessary permissions to access the S3 bucket and objects involved. This includes read/write permissions as required by the job.

Review S3 Bucket Policy: If the S3 bucket has a bucket policy, ensure that it does not inadvertently deny access to the AWS Glue job.